# Работа с формы основанными на моделях

Tags: python, django

Как будет правильнее, копировать поля из модели или по новой описывать форму с полями? Или все зависит от случая как использовать форму?

```
 class TestForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
    model = Testtest

 class TestForm(forms.Form):
    term = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Answer (score 3):

"Правильного" здесь наверное не придумаешь, все зависит от случая. Очень удобно использовать формы основанные на моделях - почитайте про 'exclude', 'fields' и т.п., это очень мощный инструмент. Но это не панацея.

Answer (score 3):

Так называемые ModelForms очень гибкие - по умолчанию поля "наследуются" от модели, в документации указано, как (в какие типы Form-полей) конвертируются Model-поля.
Вы можете исключать поля из формы, или явно описать нужные списком (как написал выше Сергей), а если вам нужны дополнительные поля, которых не было у модели - вы можете спокойно их описать, как и в обычной форме.